# How to generate absolute assets url for non-http request

Tags: php, symfony-2.7, symfony

Since Symfony-2.7 the `asset`'s method 3rd argument (a boolean that indicates whether to generate an absolute url) was deprecated.

From sources:

```
@trigger_error('Generating absolute URLs with the Twig asset() function was deprecated in 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Please use absolute_url() instead.', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

So the official way to generate it in a Symfony-3.0 compatible way became:

```
{{ absolute_url(asset('some/asset.css')) }}
```

The problem though is that the `HttpFoundationExtension` that provides the `absolute_url` relies on the "request stack" which is empty in case of non-http request.

So it returns the original path without any transformations:

```
    if (!$request = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()) {
        return $path;
    }
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/HttpFoundationExtension.php#L59

So the question is - how to generate a full url in a CLI-based application?

An **important** note: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html this advice is not actual when you use `absolute_url` helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pushing dummy request object to request_stack service, also configure request context in parameters.yml as said in sending_emails.html

```
    $request = new Request();
    // if you use locales
    $request->setLocale("en");
    // to be able to render twig asset absolute paths we have to inject dummy request
    $container->enterScope('request');
    $container->set('request', $request, 'request');
    $container->get('request_stack')->push($request);
```